# How to decrypt a simple substitution cipher where space is also encrypted by a character

Tags: encryption, substitution-cipher

I am trying to decrypt a text data encrypted with a simple substitution method with 2 steps. First, shift the alphabet of the source text by a few characters.

For example, if we shift by 2 characters, `Hello, world!` becomes `Jgnnq, yqtnf!`.

Secondly, Substitute space (`" "`) with a lower case alphabet.
For example, when g and `" "` are to be replaced, `Jgnnq, yqtnf!` becomes ultimately encrypted to `J nnq,gyqtnf!`. Now, I am having trouble with finding which character is used to replace `" "`. I was thinking of using the character with the highest occurrence frequency (except `e`, since e has the highest frequency in the English language). But I found that it may not work always.

Does anyone has any idea how to

Comment: Accept `  ` (space) as also a letter? So instead of 26 you will have 27 letters.

Comment: @kelalaka you are correct.

Comment: Clearly, the letter that has been swapped with space is the one that appears after commas. ;)

Comment: @fkraiem I also thought of this approach. but what happens when there is no comma or semi-colon in the text and the text is one line sentence?

Comment: Other approach: try to reverse the shifting first...

Comment: If you have very small ciphertext then you may get fooled by different characters following a comma. However, as long as you keep to statistics and not *rule out* other characters after a comma then you should still be able to identify space (which is more frequent than `e` in English text written down using ASCII).